# Could you help me to write this simple SQL (I haven't come up with results)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Thank you for your help.

could you help me to create a SQL statement which shows
if amount1 ($500 +$300) >amount2 ($400 +200) by 100, then result listing the two lines. I know I need to group column1 by 1001 and 1002, but couldn't come up with the rest :-(
since for column 1 1002 is larger by only by 50 (100 - 50), so shouldn't show up in results.

Thanks in advance
Jessie

| column1 | column2 | amount1 | amount2 | customer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 1 | $500 | $400 | ABC |
| 1001 | 2 | $300 | $200 | ABC |
| 1002 | 1 | $100 | $50 | CBX |

Results should be:

| column1 | column2 | amount1 | amount2 | customer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 1 | $500 | $400 | ABC |
| 1001 | 2 | $300 | $200 | ABC |

Comment: "sql" as a tag is almost useless, it is important for **you** that we propose sql syntax that you can use, so **we need to know which database you use** e.g. mysql or postgres or sql-server etc. every database vendor has a slightly different syntax for its implementation of sql

Comment: Hi Paul, Thanks for the comments. I've added sql-server to the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo could use a correlated subquery with *exists*, such as:

```
select * 
from t
where exists (
  select * from t t2
  where t2.column1 = t.column1
  group by column1 
  having Sum(amount1) > (Sum(amount2) + 100)
);
```